# during passing a value in res.redirect using string catanation extra %20 is adding in space

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
nst express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const date = require(__dirname + "/date.js");

const app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

app.post("/del",function(req,res){
    const checkBoxId = req.body.checkBox;
    const listName = req.body.listName;
    res.redirect("/"+listName);
})
```

above peice of code when i am redirecting using del route ,
let listName = "about"
insted of redirecting to localhost:3000/about
it is redirection to localhost:3000/about%20
whyyy

Comment: Sounds like you just need to trim the whitespace: `const listName = req.body.listName.trim()`. Better yet, check the response from your `/del` endpoint and sanitise the data there

Comment: but why is there a white space

Comment: We can't tell you that from the code example you've shown. It's in the data returned from your `/del` endpoint.

Comment: What does `console.log(JSON.stringify(listName))` print?